# Answer button placement on Mobile phone app

Tags: mobile-application

This question is regarding phone apps on Mobiles and Desktops. When I receive a call on my Mobile phone app "Answer" button is placed on right side of "Decline" button where as on my desktop same app "Answer" button is placed on left side of "Decline" button. Is there a specific UX reason for placing the answer button differently on Mobiles when compared to Desktops?

[Skype Incoming Call-Desktop](https://app.box.com/s/h7k9qvgfr39qg0gzf85d)

[Skype Incoming Call-Mobile](https://app.box.com/s/qzyaux96nj4z5prr5lbi)

Comment: Well spotted. On an Left to Right language interface, it makes sense to put the more common action on the left. Thus I assume on the desktop version the 'answer' button is on the left. Why is it inconsistent with the mobile interface is beyond me. I thought it might be a localisation business. But it is the same on an English Mobile. Seems just an inconsistency between the different Skype development teams.

Comment: placement of button is the same in windows phone and windows desktop.

Comment: @Awesh, you mean to say on windows phone also you have similar kind of placement of buttons in Skype?

Comment: yes, placement of button is same.http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/skype/c3f8e570-68b3-4d6a-bdbb-c0a3f4360a51

Answer (score 1):

## Platform Consistency

Most likely this is so to adhere with the platform guidelines.

[Microsoft's guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511268.aspx#commitButtons) are that the primary action is left-aligned.

Whereas [Apple's guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) are that the primary action should be right-aligned.

## Skype's Answer

Asking Skype about this, their reply was:

> As I have checked, there is no apparent reason for the different positioning of the answer button on the desktop application and the mobile application.
>
> However, I have forwarded your query to my supervisor so she could post this question to the higher departments.

So I guess it's a TBC.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to the notice of Skype. Hope they give us an answer.

Comment: +1 for going straight to the source of truth, hopefully what you get is the 'truth'.

Comment: @Izhaki Any feedback from Skype?

Comment: Not yet. If they reply, be sure I'll mention it here.